# Firefox WebDriver: Failed to connect to binary

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I have a `WebDriver` based `Java` testsuite, which I try to execute with Jenkins.
Project is imported and build was successful.

During execution of test I get following:

> Running TestRunner
>       Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@2437c6dc
>       org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console
>   output

It seems doesn't found binary, but it is located in the given path.

> Failed tests:   runBeforeTest(TestRunner): Failed to connect to binary
>   FirefoxBinary(/home/user1/Desktop/firefox/firefox-bin) on port 7055;
>   process output follows: (..)

Before execution I started a X server.

```
Xvfb :19 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
export DISPLAY=:19
firefox &
```

Versions:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3
Selenium 2.53.1
Firefox 55.0
Jenkins 2.60.3
```

Comment: Check the Firefox/Selenium version compatibility.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens : How could I do this?

Comment: Hi @plaidshirt did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same problem?

Comment: @user12345 : Yes, please check approved solution, it was caused by a version mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be a version mismatch between Selenium and Firefox.

According to a comment on one of their GitHub issues, Selenium 2.53.1 is known to work well with Firefox 47.0.1.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2527

To keep using Firefox 55, you need to use a higher version of Selenium (if it's already supported).

Comment: I changed Firefox to 47.0.1 and get the same error with this JSON: `"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Pachetul Ubuntu Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null}...`